# is the recursive function $(x_1+x_2)/(x_2-x_1) = x_3$ ever get to a point where it divides by $0$ if the starting conditions are$ x_1 = 1, x_2= 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, python

lets make a function that has 2 inputs the last value given by the formula $x_2$ and the second to last value given $x_1$ where the new $x_2$ is $(x_2+x_1)/(x_1-x_2)$ and de new $x_2$ is the past $x_2$.
I did this in python for 7 million integers and in never encountered a point where y/0 happened yet my question is will this always hold up to infinty or will it ever return undefined?
code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
x = 1
y = 2
graph = []
for i in range(1,700000):
   z = y
   y = ((x+y/(y-x)))
   x = z
   graph.append(x)

plt.plot(graph)
plt.show()
```

here is the graph of the sequence given:

[image: img]

Comment: I think you must mean "and the new $x_1$ [not $x_2$!] is the previous $x_2$". It's important to get these things right!

Comment: Should `((x+y/(y-x)))` be `((x+y)/(y-x))`? Also note that python lets you avoid intermediate variables if you like: `x,y=y,(x+y)/(y-x)`

Comment: It would also be necessary to know how the plot function interprets its input, to understand the graph.

Comment: What kind of numbers are you calculating in? Real numbers (floating-point) or rational numbers (formal quotients of arbitrary-length integers)?

Comment: @Arthur, actually I think it should be `x, y = y, (x+y)/(x-y)`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't think so. The first time through, the denominator is supposed to be $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: @Arthur, the definitions of the first paragraph are "*last value given by the formula $x_2$ and the second to last value given $x_1$*" with denominator $x_1−x_2$. Since $x$ is discarded it must represent $x_1$, and $y$ represents $x_2$. However, in figuring out why you think the first denominator should be 1 I observe that the title disagrees with the first paragraph on what the denominator is. I think we need OP to clarify or rewrite.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right. I looked at the title. Didn't catch that they differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love this question, and if I could give you more than one plus-point for it, I would.

When I did the computation exactly, with rational numbers, I saw that you cold not possibly have done it seventy thousand times without using floating-point real calculation, since the integral numerators and denominators of the corresponding rationals get immense very soon. What you need is a combinatorial or algebraic argument. And here it is, but I have to give some background.

The system of rational numbers with *odd* denominators is a ring, i.e. closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication. The commonest way of denoting this ring is $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$. The important thing about it is that there’s only one maximal ideal, namely the principal ideal generated by $2$. So it makes sense to speak of “units”, which are the rational numbers with both numerator and denominator odd; and of non units, which are those with even numerator; and to measure the “$2$-order” of a number, namely write it in the form $2^n\frac rs$ where $r$ and $s$ both are odd, $n\ge0$. The units have $n=0$; and you see that $\frac rs$ is a unit. The $2$-orders behave nicely: $\text{ord}_2(zw)=\text{ord}_2(z)+\text{ord}_2(w)$, which should be obvious. Perhaps less obvious is that $\text{ord}_2(z+w)\ge\min\bigl(\text{ord}_2(z),\text{ord}_2(w)\bigr)$, if you allow $\text{ord}_2(0)=+\infty$.

You can ignore almost all of what’s in the preceding paragraph; but if you’ve never seen this stuff before, you have to persuade yourself that even though we’re no longer dealing with integers, it does make sense to work modulo $2^N$ for a given $N$. Not only that, notice that when we work modulo $2n$, we have the nice multiplication and division rules
\begin{align}
(1+2^mz)(1+2^mw)&\equiv1+2^m(z+w)\pmod{2^{2m}}\\
\frac{1+2^mz}{1+2^nw}&\equiv1+2^m(z-w)\pmod{2^{2m}}\,.
\end{align}
If this is the first time you’ve seen this kind of stuff, you *must* verify these rules for yourself, pencil and paper. For, I’m going to be using them repeatedly.

Now, what I noticed when I did $2$-adic computations was that every third number in your sequence was not only even, but more and more highly divisible by $2$ as the indices increased by threes, and that observation gave rise to the proof you see below.

Recall that your recursion is $x_{n+1}=(x_n+x_{n-1})\big/(x_n-x_{n-1})$. I’m going to start with $x_0$ odd, and $x_1$ even, in particular, I’m going to suppose that there is a unit $u$ and a $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$-number $z$ such that
$x_{n-1}=1+2^mz$ and $x_n=2^mu$. In your setup, $m=n=1$, $z=0$, and $u=1$.

I’m about to show that $x_{n+3}=2^{m+1}u'$, and I’m going to work modulo $2^{2m}$. And so we start:
\begin{align}
x_{n-1}&=1+2^mz\\
x_n&=2^mu\\
x_{n+1}&=\frac{1+2^mu+2^mz}{-1+2^mu-2^mz}=-\frac{1+2^mu+2^mz}{1-2^mu+2^mz}
\equiv-(1+2^{m+1}u)\pmod{2^{2m}}\\
x_{n+2}&\equiv\frac{-1-2^{m+1}u+2^mu}{-1-2^{m+1}u-2^mu}
\equiv\frac{1+2^{m+1}u-2^mu}{1+2^{m+1}u+2^mu}
\equiv1-2^mu-2^mu\equiv1-2^{m+1}u\\
x_{n+3}&\equiv\frac{1-2^{m+1}u-1-2^{m+1}u}{1-2^{m+1}u+1+2^{m+1}u}
=\frac{-2^{m+2}u}{2}=-2^{m+1}u\,,
\end{align}
in which all congruences are modulo $2^{2m}$, and I really did mean those two equals signs in the last line, not that it particularly matters.

What matters is that $x_{n+3}=-2^{m+1}u+2^{2m}w$ for some $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$-number $w$, so that the $2$-order of $x_{n+3}$ is one greater than that of $x_n$. You’ll remember that with $x_0=1$, $x_1=2$, you got $x_4=4$ and $x_7=-56/61$.
And you’ll notice that none of the other $x_i$ in my computation can be zero. Similarly the $2$-order of $x_{n+2}-1$ is at least $m+1$. So your original question, whether any $x_i=x_{i+1}$, is answered in the negative.